# Create WKInterfaceButton with image and left aligned text

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to use a WKInterfaceButton for my watch app, that looks like the buttons in the watch settings:

[image: the watch settings]

with two main attributes:

- It should contain a small image on the left
- its title should be aligned to the left

I didn't found any possibility to align the title of a button to the left. I already tried to use a group instead (then it would work), but when I use a group I can't use the the shape of WKInterfaceButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While i haven't tried this myself i think what you're looking for to match the watch settings is a table view. Define a table view in the interface controller of your story board and add your image and label to the row(s). There's an example of how to do this in the [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Tables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH14-SW1) for apple kit.

Answer (score 12):

Here's how I would do it...

1. Create a button
2. Make that button type a group
3. Within that button-group, place two groups inside it. The group on the left will contain the image. The group on the right will contain a label
4. So place an image in the left group, and a label in the right group.
5. Adjust the margins, length, heights of these groups until you get the desired look.

Give the button-group a length relative to container of "1" and a height of "size to fit content"

For the inner group that will contain the image, give it a length of relative to container of "0.2" (maybe)

For the inner group on the right that will contain the label, give it a length of relative to container of "0.8" (so that together the two groups make 1)

Give both groups a height of relative to container (1)

Comment: This should be the right answer to the question in the title

Answer (score 3):

use WKInterfaceButton Content as Group and place image and label in it.